# RuntimeError: OperationalError: (2003, Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IPaddress of the instance'

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to run a **Python(version 2.7.1')** script where I am using *pymysql package* to create a table into a database from a CSV file.

It runs correctly in my local system, however, the problem appears when running the same script as a  part of a pipeline in **Google Cloud Dataflow**.

My Python function is the following one:

```
class charge_to_db(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        import pymysql

        with open(element, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read().decode("UTF-8")

        datalist = []
        for line in data.split('\n'):
            datalist.append(line.split(','))

        db = pymysql.connect(host='IPaddress', user='root', password='mypassword', database='stack_model')

        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stack_convergence")

        # create column names from the first line in fList
        up = "upper_bnd"
        primal = "primal"
        d = "dualit"
        gap = "gap_rel"
        teta = "teta"
        alpha = "alpha"
        imba = "imba_avg"
        price = "price_avg"
       # create STUDENT table // place a comma after each new column except the last
       queryCreateConvergenceTable = """CREATE TABLE stack_convergence(
                                {} float not null,
                                {} float not null,
                                {} float not null,
                                {} float not null,
                                {} float not null,
                                {} float not null,
                                {} float not null,
                                {} float not null )""".format(up, primal, d, gap, teta, alpha, imba, price)

        cursor.execute(queryCreateConvergenceTable)
```

When running this function in the cloud I'm obtaining the following **error:**

```
  RuntimeError: OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'35.195.1.40\' (110 "Connection timed out")')
```

I don't know why this error is occurring because it runs correctly in local system, so from the local system I have access to my cloud SQL instance, but not from the dataflow in the cloud.

Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 0):

On Dataflow you cannot whitelist an IP to enable Dataflow to access a SQL instance. If you would be using Java, the easiest way would be to use JdbcIO / JDBC socket factory.

But since you're using Python, then mimicking the implementation of JdbcIO.read() using Python-specific database connectivity facilities would help. There's [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701736/start-cloudsql-proxy-on-python-dataflow-apache-beam) with a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50832174/9910124) after changing some Cloud SQL settings and adding related python codes.

If this seems complex, alternatively you can [export data from Cloud SQL to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export) and then load from Cloud Storage.