# Is it safe to connect DataFlow job to Cloud MySQL with proxy (by os.system)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, proxy, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a Python job on DataFlow that need a Cloud SQL connection (and I'm a total beginner). I need to execute several MySQL queries in ParDo (Apache Beam). I am using PyMySQL and have problem authenticating, so I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61542941/13127129) answer and apparently it works:

```html
class MyDoFn(beam.DoFn):
 def setup(self):
    os.system("wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy")
    os.system("chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy")
    os.system(f"./cloud_sql_proxy -instances={self.sql_args['cloud_sql_connection_name']}=tcp:3306 &")
```

The thing is, I find this to be more of a work-around. Is it safe to authenticate this way? I would appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a safe way to use a Cloud SQL connection.  The cloud_sql_proxy uses authentication info from the Compute Engine instance to properly authenticate the connection.  See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#authentication-options for more about this.

Comment: Is it necessary to close the proxy connection right afterwards, or just leave it until the job is finished and the os system will close by itself? And thanks a lot!!

Comment: VM shutdown will terminate the proxy process, so just leave it until job termination