# run cloud sql proxy in dataflow job and connect using proxy at run time

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I am looking to connect to the GCP cloud SQL database using [cloud-sql-proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#installation) from the dataflow job.
In order for a dataflow worker node to connect cloudsql I need to set up and run a proxy in each worker node as setup.. how to achieve this with dataflow java/python logic?

Comment: You might want to try using [the Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) or the [Cloud SQL Java Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory), they provide all the same benefits of the Cloud SQL Proxy but in a native solution for Java and Python.

Comment: Hi,
I am looking to know how to setup a proxy server before a dataflow job runs.

Comment: have you checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701736/start-cloudsql-proxy-on-python-dataflow-apache-beam)?